# remove last character

Tags: php

i noticed that there are a lot of topics like this in stackoverflow, but the ones that i read are with just 1 variable, and i have two and i'm a little confuse.

so this is my code,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Provider.provider_id, provider.company_name FROM Provider");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "'".$row['provider_id']."':'".$row['company_name']."',";

}
```

I am using this to generate javascript code for Jeditable.

I need to take out the last comma, so I can wrap up with the rest of the code...

Comment: save whole string into one variable and after while process remove last character..

Comment: Just remove the last comma from your echo then.

Comment: Are you trying to create a JSON string?

Comment: @MikeBrant i think he only needs to remove the comma from the end of the loop (not each loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use an array:

```
$query = ...;
$out = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $out[] = "'".$row['provider_id']."':'".$row['company_name']."'";
}
echo implode(",",$out);
```

It looks like you're trying to output some kind of JSON though, so perhaps you could use:

```
$query = ...;
$out = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $out[$row['provider_id']] = $row['company_name'];
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: It's not quite JSON. JSON uses double quotes around strings, this is using single quotes. But probably either will work for this application. Also, `json_encode` will do proper escaping of embedded quotes.

Answer (score 2):

So i usually just stack things like this into an array and then implode:

```
$parts = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $parts[] =  "'".$row['provider_id']."':'".$row['company_name']."'";

}

echo implode(',', $parts);
```

That said it looks like youre outputting the body of a JSON string. If so you shouldnt manually build it you should use `json_encode` instead.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $data[$row['provider_id']] = $row['company_name'];

}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Provider.provider_id, provider.company_name FROM Provider");
$result = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $result .= "'".$row['provider_id']."':'".$row['company_name']."',";
}
$result = rtrim($result, ',');
```

OR

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Provider.provider_id, provider.company_name FROM Provider");
$result = array;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $result[] = "'".$row['provider_id']."':'".$row['company_name']."',";
}
$result = implode(',' $result);
```

OR

get count of records (`mysql_num_rows($query)`) and when you hit last row just do what you want